# php printing wrong timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I am in Kuala Lumpur, but when I print current time zone in php it is showing:

**Europe/Berlin**

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

isn't it supposed to show **Asia/Kuala_Lumpur**?

I am using localhost

Comment: no. it shows whatever it's been configured to show.

Comment: Well where are you setting it? Even though *you* are in Kuala Lumpur, is your server located there? We're missing a lot of information here...

Comment: I am using localhost

Comment: Right, and what do *other* aspects of your system think the time zone is? (Please add all relevant information into the question - it's painful to have to ask for one bit at a time.)

Comment: Yes.. and I too am using localhost right now to type this message, and I had to set my system's time zone before it was showing the correct date and time.. Did you do that? =)

Answer (score 2):

Can you check your php.ini file, there is an option to configure your timezone.

```
date.timezone=[Set your Value]
```

You can get the timezone values you can configure on the link below:

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

For your case it should be: Asia/Kuala_Lumpur

Answer (score 1):

[`date_default_timezone_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) returns the default timezone by:

1. Reading the timezone set using the [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)
   function (if any)
2. If PHP >= 5.4.0: Reading the TZ environment variable (if non empty).
3. Reading the value of the [`date.timezone`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) ini option (if set)

[**Manual:**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

> Prior to PHP 5.4.0 only: Querying the host operating system (if
>   supported and allowed by the OS). This uses an algorithm that has to
>   guess the timezone. This is by no means going to work correctly for
>   every situation. A warning is shown when this stage is reached. Do not
>   rely on it to be guessed correctly, and set date.timezone to the
>   correct timezone instead.